# MlModel prediction returns nil

Tags: swift, coreml, mlmodel

I converted an ONNX model to mlmodel and I'm unable to use the prediction function.
here is my model's input and output:
[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mY4H.png

i'm initializing the model and the input like this:

```
var model: dont_touch_model! 
var modelInputVector = try! MLMultiArray(shape: [1,1,13], dataType: MLMultiArrayDataType.float32)
```

I fill the vector with motion data like this:

```
modelInputVector[[0, 0, 0] as [NSNumber]] = deviceMotion.userAcceleration.x as NSNumber
modelInputVector[[0, 0, 1] as [NSNumber]] = deviceMotion.userAcceleration.y as NSNumber
modelInputVector[[0, 0, 2] as [NSNumber]] = deviceMotion.userAcceleration.z as NSNumber
```

I try to execute a prediction:

```
let modelInput = dont_touch_modelInput(sequenceinput: modelInputVector)
var modelOutput = try! model.prediction(input: modelInput)
```

and I get this error message:

```
"Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value"
```

can someone please help?

Comment: You never load the model anywhere so your `model` variable is nil.

Comment: I added it manually to Xcode and initialized it with: var model: dont_touch_model!

Comment: That doesn't load the model. You need to write `var model = dont_touch_model()`

Comment: ok I did that and I still get the same error